# how can i call 3 relationship in single join @ $this->col CRUDBOOSTER

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, crudbooster

i've been try to make 3 relationship in single join in this code :

```php
$this->col[] = array("label"=>"Jabatan","name"=>"profil_id","join"=>"profils,jabatan_id","join"=>"jabatans,nama_jabatan");`
```

but it's not work, the only i can do just make 2 relationship in single join like this code :

```php
$this->col[] = array("label"=>"Jabatan","name"=>"profil_id","join"=>"profils,jabatan_id");`
```

output from i can do : 
  [image]

i just wanna change the **id** column and showing **nama_jabatan** column from **jabatans** table
  [image]

Comment: Have tried laravel relationships? they are pretty good to mostly all things.
you can read documentations here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Are you trying to show in list view or in form?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using laravel relationships, in your model define relation and call it.

```
class Profils extends Authenticatable
{
  public function jabatans()
   {
     return $this->hasOne('jabantasmodelname');
   }
 }
```

and call this

```
 $profile = Profils::find(1)->jabatans;
```

For further you can see laravel documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)